# Webpack fast import rule

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I need to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) with [snapsvg](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg). According to *snapsvg*'s documentation, to import it with *webpack*, I need to use a loader:

```
const Snap = require(`imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0!snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js`);
```

So, in every Javascript file I use, I need to write this thing. I would like to avoid it.

### Aliased import

Is there a way, maybe in `webpack.config.js`, to specify that every time this is encoutered:

```
import snap from "snapsvg"
```

Then that line is translated into the one mentioned before? So I can avoid typing the same thing in every file.

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/483#issuecomment-314892507 ?

Comment: Yes, seems like it! Post it as an answer please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this rule](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/483#issuecomment-314892507):

Install Imports Loader (`npm i -D imports-loader`) and add this to your webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: require.resolve('snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js'),
      use: 'imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0',
    },
  ],
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    snapsvg: 'snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js',
  },
},
```

With that you can `import snap from "snapsvg"` without hassle.